# How to print the correct date in google sheet using Keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to print the current timestamp in google sheet. I'm using keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + ;` to print the current time. The timestamp is correct but when I change the format of the timestamp to date and time, the date is actually incorrect because the date is on `30 Dec 1899` as shown in the screenshot above.

There is another shortcut key which is `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ;` which print the correct date and time but I don't prefer to use this as I don't want the output to show the date. May I know is there any way for me to change the date from 30 Dec 1899 to current date when I'm using `Ctrl + Shift + ;`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice to store dates in databases as a number of days elapsed since 1<sup>st</sup> January 1900. If the date part of the timedate object is unknown (meaning that only the time parts are known), then it is assumed to be 30<sup>th</sup> December 1899 (one day before 1<sup>st</sup> January 1900) by agreement.

In the given example you create a timedate object based on the current time, so the date part is left blank. After that, if you try to format that object as a full date, then the date part is assumed to be 30<sup>th</sup> December 1899 because it is unknown.

In conclusion, you should use `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ;` if you want to work with both dates and times; or `Ctrl + Shift + ;` if you only need times (but keep in mind that it has a unknown associated date that will be represented as 30<sup>th</sup> December 1899 if formatted properly). Additionally you could use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to develop [Sheet macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros) that create datetime objects fitting your precise needs. Don't hesitate to leave a comment if you need further explanations.